# Envio de e-mail C# The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

Estou testando o envio de e-mail da aplicação para uma opção de recuperação de senha,testei diversas formas, inclusive com e-mail de outro domínio e hospedagem e tudo funciona bem, testei com e-mail do gmail e tudo funciona, mais com o e-mail do servidor não funciona.

Montei um exemplo de um código em C# que funciona perfeitamente com outro servidor e funciona com o gmail, mais não funciona com o TOP3, agradeço a ajuda.

```
 public void EnviarEmailComSenhaAcesso()
        {
            string nome = "NOME DO CONTATO";
            string EmailContato = "emailcontato@yahoo.com.br";
            string mensagem = "Mensagem";
            string login = "este e o seu login";
            string senha = "está e sua senha";

            //usando o google funciona
         //   string sUserName = "email@gmail.com";
          //  string sPassword = "";
            string sBobdy = "";

            //usando o servidor multiplique
            string sUserName = "no-replay@multiplick.com";
            string sPassword = "SENHA";


            MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
            objEmail.From = new MailAddress(sUserName.Trim());
            objEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(EmailContato, "Senha de Acesso ao site"));
            objEmail.Subject = "Recupera Senha Acesso";

            sBobdy = "Mensagem do site:\n\n" +
                                    "Nome: " + nome + "\n" +
                                    "Email: " + EmailContato + "\n" +
                                    "Login: " + login + "\n" +
                                    "Senha: " + senha + "\n" +
                                    "Mensagem: " + mensagem + "\n\n";
            objEmail.Body = sBobdy;

          //  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587 /* TLS */);
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.multiplick.com", 25 /* TLS */);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword, "");
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(objEmail);
                TempData["msg-contato"] = "A sua senha de acesso foi enviada para o seu e-mail cadastrado!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TempData["msg-contato-erro"] = "Ops..houve um problema com o envio do e - mail!Você pode tentar no telefone!";
                TempData["msg-contato-erro"] = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Tenho o erro quando usa o servidor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse erro significa que o servidor DNS não contém esse nome, está tentando da sua máquina ou do servidor de hospedagem?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não tenho uma solução exata, mas acredito que vá resolver a duvida. A uns meses atrás tive o mesmo problema que você está tendo, eu uso o serviço da GoDaddy com o SMTP: `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` eu pesquisei em 99% dos sites e não conseguia achar uma solução até que eu liguei lá e eles me informaram basicamente( e de forma bem porca):

> O nosso SMTP só funciona se estiver nos nossos servidores. Hospedagem compartilhada tem limitações.

Porque eu acredito que o meu problema era o mesmo que o seu:

1. Eu tinha a mesma Exception.
2. A Exception acontecia no **localhost**.
3. Quando eu configurava um serviço de email diferente(Google) funcionava no **localhost** normalmente.
4. Esse item provavelmente acontença(se você quiser **testar e editar** a pergunta melhor ainda), quando eu upo o serviço na hospedagem(**fora do localhost**) ele não me retornava a Exception.

Não consegui encontrar o erro DIRETAMENTE relacionado ao SMTP que você utiliza, mas eu encontrei [esse link](https://br.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/Error-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-when-sending-email-SMTP/td-p/32264) (da própria Godaddy) onde o usuário diz:

> I have contacted Go Daddy about this, and have been told that the network host will not work when running localhost, as I suspected.
>
> Eu contactei a Go Daddy, e eles disseram que o ***servidor de email***(não consegui entender a tradução literal) não irá funcionar no Localhost como eu suspeitei.

O que eu aconselho nesse momento é: Ou você ligar no serviço e provavelmente o suporte irá dizer o mesmo que o suporte da Go Daddy disse para mim, ou tire a prova por si mesmo upa o site na Hospedagem e testa o envio de e-mail, se funcionar o problema está no que foi citado na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uma consulta com o `nslookup`, o host `smtp.multiplick.com` não apareceu como sendo o MX do domínio. Em uma consulta reversa, não foi encontrado o PTR para este host. O MX do domínio que eu encontrei foi o `mail.multiplick.com`.

Troque em seu código e tente novamente:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.multiplick.com", 25);
```

Ou

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.multiplick.com", 587);
```